# Mask Pandas DataFrame on condition of inclusion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm building some Machine Learning code that deals with images. I'm having problems when masking the correct data.

So I have two columns in a pandas DataFrame, a filename of an image and its label. The problem is that it happens that there might be a label which corresponds with no image, because I labelled some images that later were discarted. I've tried to mask them out, and could certainly do some ugly thing to do it, but as I am new to Python I was hoping to get some advice.

df is a pandas DataFrame that has columns filename and file_attributes

```py
df.drop(df[df['filename'] in os.listdir(PATH)].index, inplace=True)
```

I would hope the output to drop the files not in the directory, but I get an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the function `isin()` when dealing with such condition in pandas :

```
df.drop(df[df['filename'].isin(os.listdir(PATH))].index, inplace=True)
```